# Redis sentinel auto discovery in Docker not working

Tags: docker, redis, redis-sentinel, redis-ha

The current environment is as below,

Host 1: Master in Docker Container + Sentinel in separate Docker Container

Host 2: Replica in Docker Container + Sentinel in separate Docker Container

Host 3: Sentinel in Docker Container

Replication is working fine between Master and Replica.

Sentinels in all the Hosts are able to discover the Master and Replica (verified by `SENTINEL MASTER mymaster` and `SENTINEL REPLICAS mymaster`).

But, no sentinel is able to auto discover any other sentinel (`SENTINEL SENTINELS mymaster` returns `empty array`).

In each `sentinel.conf` of the respective Sentinel, `announce-ip` and `announce-port` options have been set to the respective Host's IP and Sentinel default port (26379).

The channel `__sentinel__:hello` is receiving `hello` messages from all Sentinels (verified by running `SUBSCRIBE __sentinel__:hello` in `redis-cli` on Master node). Channel name was obtained from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074003/get-redis-master-sentinels).

Despite all these, Sentinels are not able to auto discover each other.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Docker inspect sentinel container,show output.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UrYyASas_yDTu_GubX_xxk4NfMNG1O41/view?usp=share_link